# What library does contain basic jenkins workflow groovy functions?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, intellij-idea, groovy

I am writing a junit test for my Jenkins groovy scripts. My Jenkins script that I am testing contains a method call like this:

```
error "Foo"
```

When I try to run the test from my IDE (Intellij IDEA) I get an error like this:

> No signature of method: static xxx.error() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values [Foo]

So I suppose, I need to add some library into my classpath to make this `error` function known to Runtime. I tried this maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>workflow-aggregator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

but it does't help.

So I am struggling to find what library contains these basic Jenkins workflow functions described in here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [Jenkins Pipeline Unit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) library that makes all those functions/methods like `echo` or `error` [available and known to the pipeline context](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lesfurets/jenkins/unit/BasePipelineTest.groovy#L124):

```
...
helper.registerAllowedMethod("echo", [String.class], null)
...
```

In this case every test should wrap-up the piece of code we are trying to test into a small jenkins script that will be executed by the `JenkinsPipelineUnit` engine.

Answer (score 0):

The source is located [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/ErrorStep). So based on the [pom](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L34) I would say it's in the following dependency.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow/workflow-basic-steps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried this one. Moreover, this dependency is part of the aggregated one I mentioned in the question.